# C fork() and pointers interaction

Tags: c, fork

So, I wrote this simple program: I allocate an integer (get it's pointer), fork() a few times and print the address and the value in that address.

```
int main() {
    int* p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*p) = 0;

    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    (*p)++;
    sleep(1);

    printf("%p\t%d\n", p, *p);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to be 8 times the address and then the value 8, because it gets incremented 8 times, but the output is:

```
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
0x55befa116260  1
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Each process has its own memory. Each process increments the variable once.  The result is what you should be expecting.  Processed are different from threads.  With threads, the variable would be shared. There’d be problems with indeterminate access to the variable, but things would be different.

Comment: More specifically, each process runs in its own virtual *address space*, and pointer values in user processes refer to virtual addresses, not physical ones.  That pointers in different processes have the same value does not mean that they refer to the same object in a shared-memory sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, but, why then am I seeing the same address printed? I am aware of the variables getting duplicated, but that would mean the pointer still points to the same place.

Comment: Each process is a copy of the original, more or less. They all have the same memory map, with the same virtual addresses.  But there are 8 separate copies all with the integer at the same virtual address.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh thanks. I wasn't aware of that happening. I guess that answers it.